# Alongside my book proposal, I included by mistake a chapter with some typos (just a few, but major).

Tags: etiquette, editors, publishers

Should I email the editor and resubmit the corrected version of the chapter?

I have been trying to meet a deadline so I worked very hard on my book proposal. It was polished and ready to be submitted. In the last minute, I decided to write a new introduction for one of the chapters that I submitted together with the proposal. I did not print the chapter again, so I did not see the typos, and some of the extra words left hanging in the text. Those typos are only on the first three pages of the chapter--the rest had already been edited.

Should I email the editor and let him know? He told me he already submitted the materials to the reviewers.

Comment: What exactly is a "major" typo?

Comment: two or three missing verbs. the most significant one was a combination some words left hanging from an earlier version of the sentence.

Answer (score 4):

I have never been in either pair of the shoes, but I will try to break this down: To me, it's better to lose a book deal because I reported an error in my proposal than to lose a book deal because a reviewer commented "glaring grammatical errors in the introduction."

I would suggest sending the corrected version to the editor with an apology, explaining what the errors are and invite the editor to decide if it needs to be delivered again to the reviewers. That way, you did your job as a responsible intellect, and the editor remains in control. And even the editor decides not to resend another version and later a reviewer found the errors, you're already covered from the editor's point of view. That's why I really see no harm reporting that.

Best of luck to your publishing endeavor.

Answer (score 0):

If the proposal has already gone to reviewers, then it's late in the game to be messing around like this. Let it go.

Publishers do not expect 100% clean copy. One of the functions of the publisher is copy editing.

The typos might have a slightly negative effect, but what would be much more negative would be if you came off to the editor and reviewers as an author who is pesky and is going to be a pain to work with in the future. Acquisition editors are busy people, and they don't want to spend a lot of time dealing with anxious authors.